# How to use ? question mark in for loop in C?

Tags: c, for-loop, conditional-operator

If `i` is even, `for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)`

Else if `i`is odd, `for(int j = m-1; j > 0; j--)`

I would like to combine the two conditions as follows.

```
for( (i%2==0) ? (int j = 0; j < m; j++) : (int j = m-1; j > 0; j--))
```

But it seems to fail.

Is there any way to combine the two conditions using `?` or another way in the C language?

Comment: You realize the second loop runs one fewer times than the first version, right? I'd expect them both to run the same number of times, but without context, can't be sure what's correct.

Comment: You can't use a `?:` (ternary) operator this way. Just do the obvious/simple version: `if ((i % 2) == 0) { for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) { /* do even */ } } else { for (int j = m - 1; j > 0; --j) { /* do odd */ } }`

Comment: If you just want a question mark you can do `for(int i=0; i<n ??! i<n; i++)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something a little hacky and obfuscated, like the following, but I wouldn't recommend it. This counts down from `m-1` to 0 if `i` is odd and counts up from 0 to `m-1` if `i` is even. Note that the original question counts down from `m-1` to 1, and I assumed you wanted from `m-1` to 0, so correct as needed.

Be careful with 'unexpected' input values of `m`, e.g. negatives, because the loop may not terminate when you want in that case.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i = 1;
    int m = 8;
    
    int start = i%2 ? m-1 : 0;
    int end = i%2 ? -1 : m;
    int delta = i%2 ? -1 : 1;
    
    for (int j = start; j != end; j += delta)
    {
        printf("j=%d\n", j);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `if iis odd, for(int j = m-1; j > 0; j--)` ... Funny that an "off by one" answer is selected by the OP.

Comment: jarmod, Long loop and then undefined behavior with extreme inputs like `int i = 0; int m = -1;`. `j != end` is not a sufficient stopping condition.

Comment: @Fe2O3 yes, you're right but my assumption was that the original question mistakenly terminated the loop early when `i` is odd. It was a hunch. Maybe it was a good hunch, I don't know but I wrote a solution with that assumption. I also stated exactly what the start/end values were so the OP could decide if it was correct and fix, as needed.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, and thank you. I've modified the answer with an additional warning.

Answer (score 7):

No, you can't combine them with the [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator). The operands to a conditional expression are each expressions that return a value, and the result of the conditional expression is a *single* value.

A for loop has the form `for( init expression; condition expression; iteration expression) loop-body`, it takes *three* expressions.

You're attempting to return some kind of three element `(init, condition, iteration)` tuple of *expressions* from the ternary to serve as init/condition/iteration expressions of the for loop, but you can't package those things up and then unpack them that way. The syntax is just fundamentally wrong.

Use an `if`/`else`. If you want to share the loop body, put it in a function and call the function from each loop:

```
if (i % 2 == 0) {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
    do_things(j);
  }
} else {
  for (int j = m-1; j > 0; j--) {
    do_things(j);
  }
}
```

Comment: 'Twould be a pity if `do_things()` required an abundance of discrete variables that were present in the calling function...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Not sure what your point is. Factor your code however you like.

Comment: *No, you can't ...* I should probably be banished to the deepest pits of hell for mentioning this, but [GCC's "statement expression"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) might be able to be twisted and abused enough to do what the OP proposes.  Yeah, I'll now go manually copy K&R 20 million times as penance.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Don't complicate the loop by counting up or down... Just translate the loop counter as needed:

```
void doit( int m, int i ) {
    // peculiar imbalance in OP's ranges :\
    // if i is odd, bail out BEFORE reaching 0th value
    m -= i%2;
    for( int j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
        int k = i%2 ? m - j : j;  // ternary, and begin using 'k'

        printf( "%d ", k );
    }
    putchar( '\n' );
}

int main( void ) {
    doit( 15, 0 );
    doit( 15, 1 );

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
14 13 12 11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

**EDIT:**
Bothered that other answers suggest either duplicating processing in two separate loops or duplicating a function call, below is a simplified version of the above. Like the other answers given, this version disregards the OP's unbalanced ranges for up vs. down count.

```
int main( void ) {

    for( int i = 0; i <= 1; i++ ) { // demonstrate both even and odd

        unsigned m = 10; // # of steps

        for( unsigned j = 0; j < m; j++ ) { // traverse range

            int k = i%2 ? m - j - 1: j; // descending or ascending

            printf( "%d ", k ); // Simulate processing
            /* more processing with this value */
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

(Changed to used `unsigned` to skirt the issue raised by @Chux)

---

Demonstrating effectiveness of this implementation: a ludicrous Celsius/Fahrenheit conversion:

```
int main( void ) {
    double temp = get_double( "Temperature: " );
    int i = get_int( "Is this Celsius(0) or Fahrenheit(1): " );

    for( unsigned m = 3, j = 0; j < m; j++ ) {
        switch( (i%2) ? m - j - 1: j ) {
            case 0:
                temp *= (i%2) ? 5 : 1.0/5;
                break;
            case 1:
                temp *= (i%2) ? 1.0/9 : 9;
                break;
            case 2:
                temp += (i%2) ? -32 : 32;
                break;
        }
    }

    printf( "%.2lf%s\n", temp, i%2 ? "C" : "F" );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. I wish you all the best !!!!

Answer (score 1):

The golden rule to become a successful programmer: do not complicate things just for the heck of it. Write code in the simplest, most readable way possible.

For example, this is very readable and therefore very hard to improve further:

```
if(i % 2) // odd
{
  for(int j=m-1; j > 0; j--)
  {
    do_stuff_with(something[i][j]);
  }
}
else // even
{
  for(int j = 0; j < m; j++)
  {
    do_stuff_with(something[i][j]);
  }
}
```

We *could* write a more obscure loop suiting both cases, but the benefits of doing so are questionable since the code only turns harder to read, for no obvious benefits:

```c
// not really recommended
int start;
int end;
int mod;

if(i % 2) // odd
{
  start = m-1;
  end   = -1;
  mod   = -1;
}
else // even
{
  start = 0;
  end   = m;
  mod   = 1;
}

for(int j=start; j!=end j+=mod)
{
  do_stuff_with(something[i][j]);
}
```

(This might perhaps be sensible in some scenario of manual optimization for better data cache performance, but only after actual benchmarking and finding a performance bottleneck.)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me the golden rule. I really should not complicate my code